# Create WordPress Admins To Create Posts Only Securely

Tags: wordpress

Using WordPress is a great way to learn and make progress on web development. Although, I want to make admins for each and one of my classmates to only and only create and publish posts on the web. For example, BuzzFeed has admins that create content and it tells the author name, date and time, comments and responses next to it. That's what I am aiming for. Not all of my classmates use wordpress or have ever used it so I want to find a way to create admins for them simply without creating security holes for the website itself and risking getting hacks or login attempts.

what is the best way to approach a situation like this?

anyone?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your classmates to be able to add posts you can add them as "Authors." Wordpress has a build in permission system that allows authors to only add, edit and delete posts.

If you want to have more control over the capabilities you can use a plugin like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). This will allow you to create a new role and set specific capabilities for the created user role.